# KnockoutJS - safely deleting the current item in the bindingContext

Tags: knockout.js

I have this model structure

```
function Qux()
{
    ...
}

function Bar()
{
    var self = this;

    self.quxes = ko.observableArray([]);
    mappedQuxes = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.quxes, function (item)
    {
        return new Qux(item, root);
    });
    self.quxes(mappedQuxes);

    self.deleteQux = function (qux)
    {
        self.quxes.valueWillMutate();
        self.quxes.remove(function (item)
        {
            return item.quxId() == qux.quxId();
        });
        self.quxes.valueHasMutated();
    };          

    ...
}

function FooViewModel()
{
    var self = this;

    self.bars = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON('data/app.json', function (data)
    {
        var mappedBars = [];
            mappedBars = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.bars, function (item)
            {
                return new Bar(item, self);
            });
            self.bars(mappedBars);
    });
}
```

I am using jQuery Mobile so all the "pages" I refer here are simply sections in one HTML document which I can navigate to by using links and ids.

I am on an "edit page" of a `Qux` object. This page has a "save" and "delete" function.

```
<!-- ko foreach: bars -->
    <!-- ko foreach: quxes -->  
        <form>
            ...
            <a href="#quxes" data-transition="fade" class=" btn-red" data-bind="click: commitForm }">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </a>
            <a href="#quxes" data-transition="fade" class=" btn-red" data-bind="click: function() { $parent.deleteQux($data); return true; }">
                <button type="submit">Delete</button>
            </a>
        </form>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Disregard the submit. What I would like to focus on is the delete. When I click on it, I suddenly get a blank page.

My best guess is that in the "edit" section, all the data there is bound to that specific "Qux" object. When I tried to remove it from the Bar's `self.quxes` array, that data is removed. By doing so, KO also removed all the data bound to it, therefore showing me a blank page.

Is my guess correct?

One solution is to move the "delete" button from the "edit" page to the `Qux` list page. Unfortunately, that is not possible due to some spec requirements.

If my guess is true, then how do I circumvent this problem?

Comment: Hmm, you have a submit button inside your `<a>` tag. Maybe your browser is submitting the form?

Comment: No worries about that. The submit is not triggering due to it being inside an `<a>` and jQuery Mobile handling forms differently from the traditional form submit paradigm. The button is there for aesthetic purposes only.

Comment: Its not a bug with the data causing this line always to return true? return item.quxId() == qux.quxId();

Comment: @Anders No it's not. If you pass a function like that to remove(), it will remove all `Qux` objects in the`quxes` observableArray() where that condition holds true.

Comment: yes, but if its a problem with the data it could mean null == null == true